# Error while using the color from sass file in ionic framework app

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework, sass

I am trying to use the color from sass file in my new ionic app. But, getting
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bQGB.png) while doing so.

This is my variables.scss file code:

```
$font-path: "../assets/fonts";
$app-direction: ltr;
@import "ionic.globals";
$colors: ( primary: (base: #4486F9, contrast:#000), secondary:(base: #435d8c, contrast:#000), danger: #f53d3d, light: #ffffff, dark: #222);
//Top Toolbar
$toolbar-md-background: color ($colors, primary);
@import "ionic.theme.default";
@import "ionic.ionicons";
@import "roboto";
@import "noto-sans";
```

I have also tried without using base and contrast colors in `$colors` declaration. Also, did something like this too:

```
$toolbar-md-background: color ($colors, primary,base);
```

But, it went out of vain. Getting same error once again.

Do I have to install any sass component separately in ionic framework, I am just wondering!